# Avoiding Python's Stack

Tags: python, recursion, artificial-intelligence, iteration, depth-first-search

I am trying a number of search algorithms for an generalized AI problem, one of which is depth-first-search. I have converted breadth-first-search, greedy, and A* searches from their natural recursive form into an iterative one, but am having a bit more trouble doing it `cleanly` with depth-first-search (although it's not beyond my abilities, I'm not sure the most pythonic way to do so, hence the question).

I am running into trouble with CPython's 1000 recursive-call limit for even some medium-sized problems. Successor states are generated lazily (`_generate_states` is a generator, not a list), and the path from the initial state is required.

What is the most pythonic way to move from using the call stack to an explicit stack? How much information should be stored in the stack? When backtracking (when no states return a non-empty list), what is the best way to pop dead information from the front of the stack?

```
def dfs(initial, closed_set, goal, capacity):
    if initial == goal:
        return [initial]

    for state in _generate_states(initial, capacity):
        if state not in closed_set:
            result = dfs(state, [initial] + closed_set, goal, capacity)
            if result:
                return [state] + result
    return []
```

Comment: I don't know that there is a most Pythonic way, but I'm curious if anybody else has a better answer than that. And the answer to how much information should be stored is "no more than you require for the algorithm to work".

Comment: Just a small improvement - you might get a _slightly_ faster stack if you use a [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a list.

Comment: @Omnifarious it was also the case when I optimized BFs that I was storing a lot of redundant paths (as each of the current layer nodes had the same parent path). I'm curious to see the best way to handle this aspect as well.

Comment: The non-recursive code for DFS should look almost the same as BFS, except you would use a stack instead of a queue.

Comment: I have to confess how much I hate the word "pythonic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that keeps the generators around to preserve the desired laziness property:

```
def dfs(initial, goal, capacity):
    # These three variables form the "stack".
    closed_set = {initial}
    stack = [initial]
    gens = [_generate_states(initial, capacity)]

    while stack:
        cur = stack[-1]
        gen = gens[-1]
        try:
            state = next(gen)
        except StopIteration:
            # This node is done
            closed_set.discard(cur)
            gens.pop()
            stack.pop()
            continue

        if state == goal:
            return stack

        if state not in closed_set:
            closed_set.add(state)
            stack.append(state)
            gens.append(_generate_states(state, capacity))

    return None
```

Note that the path *is* the stack when the target is located, because the stack is a record of the nodes visited to get to the current node.

Comment: You used `path` which is undefined. Did you mean to use `stack` instead?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you know how to implement DFS iteratively using a stack (its basically the same as for BFS, just LIFO instead of FIFO), so I'll post just some general tipps.

- When implementing DFS iteratively, you should use `collections.deque` for the stack, which is optimized for quickly appending and popping elements.
- You should definitely use a set for the `closed_set` instead of a list. (Or a map {state: depth} if you want to find the shortest path.)
- For keeping track of the path, you could create a wrapper class, encapsulating your current state and a reference to the previous one (basically a linked list of states), or use a map of predecessor states.

Not sure how to make use of the generator in this case, though, so your stack will hold up to *depth x branching-factor* elements... or maybe you could put the generator on the stack, instead of the actual elements? Just an idea...

Comment: `deque` is really only needed for FIFOs. Plain old lists are performant for LIFOs; no elements need to be shifted for `append()` or `pop()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would create an iterative depth-first search. It uses `candidate_states` as a stack of states that should be explored next. You can reconstruct the path from any visited node to the initial node using the `parents` dictionary.

```
def reconstruct_path(state, parents):
    path = []
    while state != None:
        path.append(state)
        state = parents[state]
    path.reverse()
    return path

def dfs(initial, goal):
    visited_states = set()
    candidate_states = [initial]
    parents = {initial: None}
    while len(candidate_states) > 0:
        cur_state = candidate_states.pop()
        if cur_state in visited_states: continue
        if cur_state == goal:
            return reconstruct_path(cur_state, parents)
        for state in _generate_states(cur_state):
            parents[state] = cur_state
            candidate_states.append(state)
    return None
```

Comment: I used the same dictionary technique when writing the BFS solution.